# QWebView needs administrator rights in Windows 7 to access Site over https

Tags: qt, windows-7, qwebview

I use a QWebView to access a web page over https. I already applied this tip http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/5861, to ignore SSL errors. However, on Windows 7 I need to run my app with administrator rights to access the web page.

Any suggestions how I can access web pages via a QWebView over https without admin rights?